# how to divide continous requests among 2 servers with x% requests being sent to one & 100-x to other

Tags: java, probability

I have a queue of requests(in which requests keep coming). I have to handle these requests one by one and send these requests to two servers such that x% requests go to first server and 100-x % go to second server. I need to implement java function which tells to which server the specific request should be sent.

I tried generating a random number between 1-100 & sending the requests between 1 to x to server 1 and others to serer 2. But this doesn't work properly. 
Is there a better way handle this issue?

Comment: Yes, buy a hardware load balancer.  I wouldn't do such a thing in code:http://www.hardwareloadbalancer.com/

Comment: i need to do it with code only.

Comment: Then show us what you've got so far, or be more precise explaining the problem. Your solutions sounds doable.

Comment: The problem with above solution is that :-
suppose I want to sent 90% calls to machine 1 & 10% to machine 2. If I consider first 100 requests, and I get random number always below 90, so I will send all the requests to machine 1. So the ratio of 9:1 is not maintained.

Comment: does redirecting requests is enough? what about sticky session? do you want to keep the user connected to the same server? I would go for out of the box solution, if possible. There are heaps of info here: http://serverfault.com/questions/174097/how-can-i-balance-incoming-web-traffic-amongst-n-apache-servers

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is either [Weighted Round Robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_round_robin) or Dynamic Round Robin which both have well known implementations published.